# Given a list of numbers, write a function that gives the largest interval, along with the size of it. Ex. 2, 4, 9, Left=4, Right=9 Interval=5

Tags: r

```
IntervalFinder<-function(x) {
   sort(x)
   n=length(x)
   IntervalsList=c()
   for (i in x) {
   if (i <= n) {
   Int1= x[i]
   Int2= x[i+1]
   Interval= Int2-Int1
   IntervalsList=c(IntervalsList, Interval)
if ((Interval==max(IntervalsList))) {
LInt=Int1
   RInt=Int2
   IntervalSize=Interval}
  else
  {
  stop()
  }
  }
}
cat("The left interval is", LInt, ", the right interval is", RInt, "and the interval size is", Interval)
}
> IntervalFinder(x)
Error in IntervalFinder(x) :
```

The list x was previously defined after a lot of trial and error but for the sake of convienence use the one in the title. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `IntervalFinder(c(2,4,9))` seems to work fine for me and gives the expected result. You seem to be recreating `?diff` in a roundabout way however. There should be no need for a loop here - see `dx <- diff(x); md <- which.max(dx); cat(x[md], x[md+1], dx[md])`